# how can I solve this problem? `You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.` scss react

Tags: reactjs, sass

I wanna to use GoGO template in React, but i have this problem.

```
Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (29:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| 
| var render = function render() {
>   var css = import('./assets/css/sass/themes/gogo.' + color + '.scss').then(function (x) {
|     var MainApp = require('./App').default;
| 
    at eval (index.js:1)
    at Object../src/index.js (main.f444d441.js:6169)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.f444d441.js:724)
    at fn (main.f444d441.js:101)
    at eval (webpack:///multi_(:3005/webpack)-dev-server/client?:5:18)
    at Object.0 (main.f444d441.js:6180)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.f444d441.js:724)
    at main.f444d441.js:791
    at main.f444d441.js:794
```

I tried different approuch but I can't solved this problem.

This is a link to source code page.
https://themeforest.net/item/gogo-react-bootstrap-4-admin-dashboard/22544383/comments?page=5

webpack.config.js

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Webpack Config
 */
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const FriendlyErrorsWebpackPlugin = require('friendly-errors-webpack-plugin');
// const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

// Webpack uses `publicPath` to determine where the app is being served from.
// In development, we always serve from the root. This makes config easier.
const publicPath = '/';

// Make sure any symlinks in the project folder are resolved:
const appDirectory = fs.realpathSync(process.cwd());
const resolveApp = relativePath => path.resolve(appDirectory, relativePath);

// plugins
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");

const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

// the path(s) that should be cleaned
let pathsToClean = [
    'dist',
    'build'
]

// the clean options to use
let cleanOptions = {
    root: __dirname,
    verbose: false, // Write logs to console.
    dry: false
}

module.exports = {
    entry: ["babel-polyfill", "react-hot-loader/patch", "./src/index.js"],
    output: {
        // The build folder.
        path: resolveApp('dist'),
        // Generated JS file names (with nested folders).
        // There will be one main bundle, and one file per asynchronous chunk.
        // We don't currently advertise code splitting but Webpack supports it.
        filename: 'assets/js/[name].[hash:8].js',
        chunkFilename: 'assets/js/[name].[hash:8].chunk.js',
        // We inferred the "public path" (such as / or /my-project) from homepage.
        publicPath: publicPath,
        hotUpdateChunkFilename: 'hot/hot-update.js',
        hotUpdateMainFilename: 'hot/hot-update.json'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './src/index.js',
        compress: true,
        port: 3005, // port number
        historyApiFallback: true,
        quiet: true
    },
    // resolve alias (Absolute paths)
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            Components: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/'),
            Containers: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/containers/'),
            Assets: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets/'),
            Util: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/util/'),
            Routes: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/routes/'),
            Constants: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/constants/'),
            Redux: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/redux/'),
            Data: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/data/')
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "html-loader",
                        options: { minimize: true }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"]
            },
            // Scss compiler
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    "css-loader",
                    "sass-loader",
                    "style-loader",
                    // "postcss-loader"
                ]
            },
            // {
            //     test: /\.scss$/,
            //     use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            //         use: [{
            //             loader: "css-loader"
            //         }, {
            //             loader: "sass-loader"
            //         }],
            //         fallback: "style-loader"
            //     })
            // }

            // {
            //     test: /\.scss$/,
            //     use: [
            //         'style-loader',
            //         'css-loader',
            //         'postcss-loader',
            //         'sass-loader',
            //         'postcss-loader'
            //         {
            //             loader: 'sass-resources-loader',
            //             options: {
            //                 // Provide path to the file with resources
            //                 resources: 'src/assets/css/sass/themes/gogo.light.purple.scss',
            //
            //                 // Or array of paths
            //                // resources: ['./path/to/vars.scss', './path/to/mixins.scss']
            //             },
            //         },
            //     ],
            // },
        ]
    },
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new UglifyJsPlugin({
                cache: true,
                parallel: true,
                uglifyOptions: {
                    compress: false,
                    ecma: 6,
                    mangle: true
                },
                sourceMap: true
            }),
            new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})
        ]
    },
    performance: {
        hints: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? "warning" : false
    },
    plugins: [
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            {from:'src/assets/img',to:'assets/img'},{from:'src/assets/fonts',to:'assets/fonts'}
        ]), 
        new FriendlyErrorsWebpackPlugin(),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(pathsToClean, cleanOptions),
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: "./public/index.html",
            filename: "./index.html",
            favicon: './public/favicon.ico'
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "assets/css/[name].[hash:8].css"
        })
    ]
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "gogo-react",
  "version": "2.0.2",
  "description": "Gogo - React Bootstrap 4 Admin Dashboard Template",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --hot --progress --open",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "reactjs"
  ],
  "author": "Colored Strategies",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.19",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.2",
    "css-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^2.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.47.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.8.2",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.7.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.5.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.8.3",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.1",
    "react": "^16.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.1.3",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.5",
    "url-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.27.1",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.11.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@date-io/moment": "0.0.2",
    "availity-reactstrap-validation": "^2.0.4",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^0.3.0",
    "classnames": "2.2.6",
    "draft-js": "^0.10.5",
    "fine-uploader": "^5.16.2",
    "firebase": "^5.3.0",
    "formik": "^1.5.4",
    "install": "^0.12.2",
    "jalali-moment": "^3.3.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "material-ui": "^0.20.2",
    "material-ui-persian-date-picker-utils": "^0.1.2",
    "material-ui-pickers": "^2.0.4",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "npm": "^6.5.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "rc-slider": "^8.6.1",
    "rc-switch": "^1.6.0",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-autosuggest": "^9.3.4",
    "react-big-calendar": "^0.19.2",
    "react-block-ui": "^1.1.3",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.7.4",
    "react-circular-progressbar": "^1.0.0",
    "react-contextmenu": "^2.9.4",
    "react-datepicker": "^1.5.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-fine-uploader": "^1.1.0",
    "react-headroom": "^2.2.4",
    "react-intl": "2.4.0",
    "react-lines-ellipsis": "^0.13.2",
    "react-loadable": "5.4.0",
    "react-mousetrap": "^0.2.0",
    "react-perfect-scrollbar": "^1.1.1",
    "react-quill": "^1.3.1",
    "react-rater": "^5.0.3",
    "react-redux": "5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scroll-to-component": "^1.0.2",
    "react-select": "^2.0.0-beta.7",
    "react-sortablejs": "^1.3.6",
    "react-table": "^6.8.6",
    "react-tagsinput": "^3.19.0",
    "react-transition-group": "^1.2.0",
    "reactstrap": "^6.5.0",
    "redux": "4.0.0",
    "redux-saga": "^0.16.0",
    "sass-resources-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "sortablejs": "^1.6.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "sweetalert2": "^8.8.7",
    "video.js": "^7.3.0",
    "yup": "^0.27.0"
  }
}
```

Please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using latest version of react?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using latest version of `react` then no need to set `loader` in `webpack.config.js` file.

You can directly do this,

```
npm install sass-loader
```

And you can start using your `scss` files in the project.

Comment: i have installed `"sass-loader": "^7.1.0",` in my project. but i still have the error.

Comment: @HamedRahmani what is the error? Have you cleared your webpack.config.js file, whatever you have added?

Comment: i have updated webpack.json.js in question, please see that.

Comment: @HamedRahmani delete your node_modules folder and try npm install. Don't delete package.json file.

Answer (score 0):

It is about files which start with a dot being hidden by his os and failing to copy them.

In project directory there should be a ”.babelrc” and ”.eslintrc” files and the problem occurs when ”.babelrc” file is missing. Maybe you should also check it when you have time.